# Apollo Client useLazyQuery not starting

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

In the following code, checkme() is never fired

```
import { useMutation, useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { LOGOUT_USER_QUERY, CURRENT_USER } from '../graphql/user';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

export default function Logout(props) {
  const [logoutUser, { loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGOUT_USER_QUERY);
  const [checkMe, { loading: meLoading, error: meError }] = useLazyQuery(CURRENT_USER);

  const onLogout = async () => {
    await logoutUser();
    Cookies.remove('token');
    checkMe();

  }
  return (
    <div className="btn" onClick={onLogout}>{props.children}</div>
  )
}
```

logoutUser() successfully runs and returns

```
{"data":{"logout":{"status":"TOKEN_REVOKED","message":"Your have been logged out","__typename":"LogoutResponse"}}}
```

There are no errors, the query is never sent.

Am I missing somthing?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
checkMe({ variables: {} });
```

The method returned by `useLazyQuery` requires a `variables` object, even if you don't pass any variables to it.